# Entering text in an iPhone app via the Script Editor in Instruments

Tags: ios, xcode, instruments

I'm generating a script in the Script Editor of Instruments by using the `Recording Manual User Interface Actions into Automation Scripts` feature of Instruments.

Whilst recording the script I can capture taps and swipes but I can't capture text being entered in a form field.

Any suggestions?

Comment: a suggestion... take a look at tuneup.js. (http://www.tuneupjs.org/) It makes iOS UI automation much more pleasant, and extends the functionality of UIATextField so that you can call typeString directly on the TextField, instead of tapping and then using the messy keyboard call

Answer (score 0):

The Keyboard isn't technically part of the app, so actions you perform on it won't be captured. After tapping on the form field, insert

`UIATarget.localTarget().frontMostApp().keyboard().typeString("Text you would like to type");`

before the next action... you may need to add a short delay to ensure the keyboard pops up before attempting to type